Calibration off on MacBook Pro M1 Max chip using SypderX Elite
I have been using a SpyderX Elite to calibrate MacBook Pro 2021 (currently running on Sonoma 14.5).
My goal has been to calibrate the screen to be able to proof my photographs for printing. However, the MacBook's screen even after calibration, shows inaccurate results. I did some test prints and found while the screen shows a highly saturated image with a lot of contrast, in reality (through the print) I have a very flat image. The ICC profiles, also do not show accurately on the MacBook Pro, I have tried viewing them on both Lightroom Classic and on Photoshop but they do not show accurately.
An example of an issue with the ICC profiles is a strange blue tone that show up when on select the ICC profile.
For calibration I have tried different settings:
80cd/m2 5000k (due to the suggestion of my printing company) and 120 cd/m2 65000 (with the recommendation of data color customer service) but there was not any difference in the results. (True Tone, auto brightness are off.)
I went to the company that prints my work, and their monitor, a BenQ, showed my work very accurately. I was encouraged by the company to purchase a BenQ to work around my problem. However, the problem still persisted: after purchasing the BenQ the screen matched the test prints perfectly for about 1 week and then suddenly the BenQ screen started to look like the MacBook screen and that strange blue color and over saturation/ contrast appeared. No matter what I tried I could not stop this from happening. I even contacted their support and tried resetting the monitor, changing the color set up of the monitor and display options on the McBook Pro.
During this week I had done nothing that I'm aware of to change the display's setting.
Is there a way to calibrate MacBook Pro's screen accurately? If so, what could be the cause of my challenges?
I feel that with this calibration through SpyderX, I am so inaccurate that the photos don't even look good on screen, let alone printed.
Thank you so much for your help!
